# Load component dynamically insede HTML modal with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to load components dynamically, I'm using jsPanel to create a window and would like to pass which module will be created inside this window.
Is it possible to do this, below code snippet, openWindow is called from a button, * my-component * is any of the components of my application that I need to load into the contents of the panel that will open.

```
openWindow(event) {
  jsPanel.create({
    theme: 'gainsboro',
    headerTitle: 'my panel #1',
    position: 'center-top 0 58',
    contentSize: '450 250',
    content: '<meu-component></meu-component>',
  });}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular dynamic component loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510425/angular-dynamic-component-loading)